# Why is this pyglet basic program slowing down

Tags: performance, python-3.4, frame-rate, pyglet

I am currently using pyglet 1.2alpha1 on top of python 3.4, after having been using pygame for a while. In pygame, it is trivial to have the main loop running as fast as it can, providing a clear way of benchmarking changes and taking note of fps drops. My goal isn't to build a game in itself but a simulation-like and the faster it runs, the happier I will be.

I am having quite a hard time figuring out how to setup the framerate of pyglet in the same fashion. I know I need to deactivate default vsync option of the window and to remove the default fps cap, but that doesn't solve the problem. My actual tentative to set framerate loose is described in the problematic code lower, which fails miserably (capped at 60 fps).

Plus, after a few seconds, the program described lower slow downs to unbearable speeds, even though it's work load doesn't change at all. I figured out that the call to update_true_fps is the culprit, although I do not see why: if it can run at 60 fps at first, why should it run at 2 fps after half a minute?

Problematic code:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

class Pyg:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = pyglet.window.Window()
        self.fps = 0
        pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(0)
        self.window.set_vsync(False)
        pyglet.clock.schedule(self.tick)
        self.update_true_fps(1)
        fps_display = pyglet.clock.ClockDisplay()

        @self.window.event
        def on_draw():
            self.window.clear()
            fps_display.draw()
            self.fps_label.draw()

    def tick(self,dt):
        if dt != 0:
            self.fps = 1.0/dt
        self.update_true_fps()

    def update_true_fps(self):
        self.fps_label = pyglet.text.Label(text="FPS:"+str(self.fps),x=self.window.width//2,\
            y=20, anchor_x='center')

    def run(self):
        pyglet.app.run()

a = Pyg()
a.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason it is slow is because you are generating too many Label objects.  Labels are not well optimized in Pyglet and involve many operations that are generally slow.  Instead of creating a label every tick, generate one only when drawing, or better yet, cache the object and just change the text when the fps changes.  You could also log the values to the console, bypassing expensive graphics operations.  As for slowing gradually over time, it could be a pyglet bug, memory leak, etc.  If you don't create so many Labels, you shouldn't run into the slowdown.